# Create a dictionary inside a dictionary based on the data from a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'd like to create a dictionary inside a dictionary from the data from my CSV. The thing is I don't have the knowledge yet to do it, I've tried searching the answers here and on other sites but it always comes up empty or too complicated for me.

Sample code I used for reading the CSV file.

```
columnnames =  ["address", "date", "time", "resource", "method", "endpoint", "pre_params", "cond_ep", "even_ep", "version", "status", "tail"]
data = pd.read_csv("log.csv", header=None, skiprows=2, names=columnnames)
```

Sample result from the read_csv using python:

```
['127.0.0.1', '12-Jun-2019', '00:0:00', '0', 'GET', '/api/test_url.php?client_code=MAM01', '/api/test_url.php', '/api/', 'api', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '80 -"']
['127.0.0.1', '12-Jun-2019', '00:0:04', '0', 'GET', '/api/test_url.php?client_code=test', '/api/test_url.php', '/api/', 'api', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '80 -"']
['127.0.0.1', '12-Jun-2019', '00:0:00', '0', 'GET', '/api/test_url.php?client_code=test', '/api/test_url.php', '/api/', 'api', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '80 -"']
```

So basically I want to create a sample dictionary like this:

```
sample_dictionary = {
                 "/api/test_url.php?client_code=MAM01":{
                               "address": "127.0.0.1",
                               "time": "00:0:04",
                               "date": "12-Jun-2019",
                               "status": "GET",
                               "count": 1
                       },
                  "/api/test_url.php?client_code=test":{
                               "address": "127.0.0.1",
                               "time": "00:00",
                               "date": "12-Jun-2019",
                               "status": "GET",
                               "count": 2
                       }
                 }
```

The **count** key will add 1 if the **api** belongs to the same **date** and **time**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't allow to create a `dictionary` with a `duplicate key` as you want to `API URL` as a dictionary key, you should use a `counter` variable as a `dictionary key`. like I'm using `list index` as a dictionary key.

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

rows = [
['127.0.0.1', '12-Jun-2019', '00:0:00', '0', 'GET', '/api/test_url.php?client_code=MAM01', '/api/test_url.php', '/api/', 'api', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '80 -"'],
['127.0.0.1', '12-Jun-2019', '00:0:04', '0', 'GET', '/api/test_url.php?client_code=test', '/api/test_url.php', '/api/', 'api', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '80 -"'],
['127.0.0.1', '12-Jun-2019', '00:0:00', '0', 'GET', '/api/test_url.php?client_code=test', '/api/test_url.php', '/api/', 'api', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '80 -"']
]

sample_dictionary = {}
for index, row in enumerate(rows):
    count=0
    date = parser.parse(row[1])
    if date.date() == datetime.now().date():
        count = 1

    sample_dictionary[index] = dict(api=row[5],address=row[0], time=row[2], date=row[1], status=row[4],
                                             count=count)

print(sample_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
sample_dictionary = {}

for filename in files:
   #Code to read file
     ......
    for row in filename:
        sample_dictionary[filename]={
                     "address": row[0],
                               "time": row[2],
                               "date": row[3],
                               "status": row[4],
                               "count": row[5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your csv by the dates
2. Parse rows

(you can do 1,2 any order)

3. Python

```py
ret = {}
for i,row in enumerate(rows):
    #check for duplicate times
    count = 0
    index = i
    while(row[1] == rows[i+1][1] and row[2] == rows[i+1][2]): 
      count += 1
      index +=1
    ret[str(row[5])] = {
        'address': row[0],
        'time': row[2],
        'date': row[3],
        'status': row[4],
        'count': count
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no count in you csv file

you can use below code and you can add count also

````
res = {}
with open("sample.csv","r")as f:
  data = csv.reader(f)
  for row in data:
        res[row[5]] = {
        "address":row[0],
        "time":row[2],
        "date":row[1],
        "status":[4]
        }
print(res)```


**Note.***  : What you are using as a key is not uniqe so every time you are replacing with new data
Please **make sure in dictionary you key should be uniqe**
````